# How do I delete rows in mysql where a specific field is duplicated chronologically next to the other duplication

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates

**Foreword**

I know that there are a number of 'delete duplicate row' solutions on here already, but I feel my query differs substantially enough to warrant a new question.

**Background**

My table serves as a historical archive of all product price points, overtime, by country.  It will keep the historical data indefinitely.

I have a daily 'price' feed which contains 7 days worth of product price history and 7 days worth of future product prices.  The data contains prices by 'country', 'product code' (sku), 'price' and 'date from' date.  There is no 'date to'; the relevant price (on a given day) is derived from the 'date from' field.

Each day there are a number of duplicates that would usually exist; as mostly the same data is sent day after day, and a given product-price may appear up to 14 times; because it is sent daily over 14 days.  I overcome this with the UNIQUE KEY of 'sku_country_date_index' ('sku', 'country', 'date_from') - where this prevents these types of duplicates.

However, the sending system isn't particularity smart and fairly often sends price change data even if the price was already at that price on the last recorded previous date e.g. "2015-01-01 @ £10", "2015-01-03 @ £10".  I would like to remove these unnecessary price rows.

Other solutions posted here, provided information on deleting exact duplicate rows; e.g. delete all rows, bar one, where a price for product X is duplicated - this isn't suitable, as a price can go up and down over time and may have that same price at a later date (with price changes in between).

**Question**

How do I delete rows in mysql where a specific field is duplicated chronologically next to the other duplication.

**Setup**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `price` (
  `import_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`import_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sku_country_date_index` (`sku`,`country`,`date_from`),
  KEY `sku_index` (`sku`),
  KEY `country_index` (`country`),
  KEY `date_from_index` (`date_from`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Example Data:

```
REPLACE INTO `price`
(`country`, `sku`, `price`, `date_from`)
VALUES
('uk', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-01'),
('uk', '123', '11.00', '2015-01-04'),
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-06'),
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-09'),
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-13'),
('uk', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-16'),
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-20'),
('uk', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-25'),
('uk', '124', '10.00', '2015-01-06'),
('uk', '125', '10.00', '2015-01-06'),
('ie', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-06'),
('ie', '123', '14.00', '2015-01-07'),
('ie', '125', '10.00', '2015-01-06')
```

Requirements:

Delete the following two rows, as they are not required to determine a product price on a given day -

```
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-09'),
('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-13'),
```

The solution can be part of the CREATE or REPLACE statements - or even be a subsequent DELETE.

**My Approach**

For reference; the below is the approach I took; which unfortunately deletes too many rows.  It doesn't take into account that a price can be duplicated if it has other prices in between.

```
DELETE FROM `price` WHERE `import_id` IN (
  SELECT t1.import_id
  FROM `price` t1, `price` t2
  WHERE 1
  AND t1.date_from > t2.date_from
  AND t1.sku = t2.sku
  AND t1.price = t2.price
  AND t1.country = t2.country
)
```

Comment: so basically days `04` and `05 ` are redundant because the price hadn't changed since it was initially set $9 on `03`? you sure you want to do this, because removing those days will make it harder to query for "what was the price on specific day X".

Comment: fair point based on the data provided; my example doesn't make it clear that for most consecutive days, there is no record.  i have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @LewisMatthews does  the  table always ordered by country, date_from ?

Comment: Hi @splash58, no - not necessarily I'm afraid.

Comment: i have the solution but you will need to sort the table before because it uses previous and next rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete d
  from t1 d 
    join t1 dd 
      on d.import_id = dd.import_id + 1 
      and d.sku = dd.sku 
      and d.price = dd.price 
      and d.country = dd.country
```

if table is unsorted, we can use the idea from the solution above to receive set of unnecessary import_id

```
set @n:=0;
set @m:=0;
delete 
  from t1 
  where t1.import_id in (
     select d.import_id
        from  
           (select @n:=@n+1 AS row_number, import_id, country, sku, price, date_from 
              from t1 order by country, date_from) as d
              join 
                 (select @m:=@m+1 AS row_number, import_id,country, sku, price, date_from 
                    from t1 order by country, date_from) as dd 
              on d.row_number = dd.row_number + 1 
              and d.sku = dd.sku 
              and d.price = dd.price 
              and d.country = dd.country)
```

Comment: Hi @splash58, the above works perfectly against my sample, which I formatted and structured to be easily read.  Unfortunately the actual table isn't ordered as nicely.  if I were to use your answer, would you suggest I used a temporary table, or multiple sub-selects (one for each join)?  i also came across ALTER TABLE x ORDER BY y, but doesn't seem to work on my DB, and doesn't seem particularly elegant or efficient.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, based on the principle being sound.  I just need to determine the best way to structure the data before passing it.

Comment: But the better way is to maintain the table in a sorted state

Comment: loving it. yes, the updated answer is pretty much what I was suggesting when I said 'multiple sub-selects', but you've now probably just saved me about 4 hours work!!! many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to keep the one row with the lowest import_id given a set of records where the country, sku, and price are the same.

I *think* this will do the trick (warning, untested):

```
DELETE p2.*
FROM price p1
  INNER JOIN price p2
    ON p2.country = p1.country
       AND p2.sku = p1.sku
       AND p2.price = p1.price
       AND p2.import_id > p1.import_id;
```

Comment: Hi R.L. Byrd,  I've tried a variation of this already; unfortunately it deletes too many rows. It doesn't take into account that a price can be duplicated if it has other prices in between.  I've updated my post with the code I was using.

Comment: The SQL provided deletes too much - ('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-09'), ('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-13'), ('uk', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-16'), ('uk', '123', '9.00', '2015-01-20'), ('uk', '123', '10.00', '2015-01-25')